# Scala spark UDF Function - Change to dinamic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reflection, user-defined-functions

I am working on a Scala function that basically does the following: it receives a DataFrame that has a column named extractive_candidates of type String with values like this:

```
"\[{'id': '2568', 'score': 0.80874604, 'contentType': 'web'}, {'id': '82', 'score': 0.78342134, 'contentType': 'faq'}, {'id': '1219', 'score': 0.78035796, 'contentType': 'faq'}, {'id': '2570', 'score': 0.7795736, 'contentType': 'web'}\]"
```

The function I have creates or replaces the extractive_candidates column by generating a column of type Array of structs. The structure is of the type:

##########################################

`StructType(Seq(   StructField("id", StringType, nullable = false),   StructField("score", DoubleType, nullable = false),   StructField("contentType", StringType, nullable = false) ))`

##########################################

Here is the function i want to change:

##########################################

```
val parseJsonUDF = udf((jsonString: String) => {
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val correctedJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("'", "\"")
  val parsedData = parse(correctedJsonString).extract[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
  parsedData.map { item =>
    (item("id").toString,"", item("score").toString.toDouble,item("contentType").toString)
  }
})

val newColumn = "newColumn"
var auxDF = df.withColumn(newColumn, parseJsonUDF(col(originColumnName)))

if (originColumnName == destinationColumnName){
  auxDF = auxDF.drop(col(destinationColumnName)).withColumnRenamed(newColumn,destinationColumnName)

}else{
  auxDF = auxDF.withColumnRenamed(newColumn,destinationColumnName)

}

val finalDF = auxDF.withColumn(destinationColumnName,
  expr(s"transform(" + destinationColumnName + ", x -> struct(x._1 as id, x._2 as faq_title_desc, x._3 as score, x._4 as contentType))")
)

finalDF
```

}
}

##########################################

What I want to change in the function is to make it dynamic in such a way that it receives a parameter named structSchema with a value like:
"id:string, faq_title_desc:string, score:double, contentType:string"``

and is able to generate the structure dynamically, and when calling the function with withColumn, it generates the new column using the fields in structSchema.

and is able to generate the structure dynamically, and when calling the function with withColumn, it generates the new column using the fields in structSchema.

I have tried to do it in many ways, but I always get this error:
*java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported*

##########################################

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

// Parse the schema string to extract field names and types
val fieldSchema = structSchema.split(",")
  .map(_.trim.split(":"))
  .map { case Array(name, typeString) => (name, typeString) }

// Convert the JSON string to a Seq[Map[String, Any]]
val correctedJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("'", "\"")
val parsedData = parse(correctedJsonString).extract[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]

// Define a helper function to cast the value to the desired type
def castValue(value: Any, typeName: String): Any = {
  typeName match {
    case "string" => value.toString
    case "double" => value.toString.toDouble
    // You can extend this with more types if needed
    case _ => value // Default to keep as is
  }
}

// Map each item in the JSON to the desired format based on the schema
parsedData.map { item =>
  fieldSchema.map { case (fieldName, fieldType) =>
    (fieldName, castValue(item(fieldName), fieldType))
  }.toMap
}
```

##########################################

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you please add input and expected output ?

Comment: input is a dataframe with all columns string
output is a dataframe with all columns + new column type Array of Struct defined in structSchema string var

Comment: the function always do the same new Array struct column: id, score and contentType:
  val parsedData = parse(correctedJsonString).extract[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]
  parsedData.map { item =>
    (item("id").toString,"", item("score").toString.toDouble,item("contentType").toString)
  }

i want to change this for use structSchema value to generate new column. For example:
structSchema = "column1:string, column2:string"

then the new column will has this kind of struct, just 2 columns not 3

Comment: Have you tried this - `from_json($"originColumnName", ArrayType(MapType(StringType, StringType)))` then use `transform` function to transform to your desired schema.